# Trouble grabbing names of different participants from a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to get only the name of different participants from a webpage but when I run my script below, it fetches exactly nothing. It doesn't throw any error either. I know the content is heavily dynamic and not available in page source but still there are several ways out there to fetch them, as in using script tag or public api available in dev tools. I've tried to find all of them but got no clue to move forward.

[Website address](https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AC/B151/C1/D50/E2/F163/)

[These are the names in the image](https://filebin.net/t9cs239tvldt6zi0) which I would like to grab. When the page is open, the `Esports` tab in left panel should be selected automatically.

This is I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'find the link above'

res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
for items in soup.select(".gll-MarketGroup_Wrapper"):
    data = [item.text for item in items.select("[class$='_NameContainer']")]
    print(data)
```

***How can I get only the names from that site using requests?***

Comment: What does `res.text` look like?

Comment: Can't check `bet365.com.au` it is forbidden in my country. Nice :)

Comment: This is the [response text](https://pastebin.com/A9cLvf0r) that I'm getting.

Comment: Response does not contain required data. You have to use Selenium to get it.

Comment: @Alderven No he does not. He just needs to find the request that contains the data he wants. Selenium is not the answer for everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using a weird api endpoint that the website has, I had to parse it using regex. However, sometimes this takes multiple attempts if you are requesting the endpoint too often. If you can't find a better way to go about this then this should work alright. Sorry this isn't 100%

## Code

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def attempt_get_api(attempt):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    url = 'https://www.bet365.com.au/SportsBook.API/web?zid=0&pd=%23AC%23B151%23C1%23D50%23E2%23F163%23&cid=13&ctid=13'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
    text = r.text
    #print(text)
    games = re.finditer(r'NA=(.*?);', text)
    print('Attempt = ' + str(attempt))

    activated=False
    for game in games:
        activated=True
        if 'v' in game.group():
            print(game.group(1))

    if not activated:
        print(r.text)
        if attempt > 5:
            print("Too many attempts, quitting.")
            quit()
        attempt_get_api(attempt+1)

attempt_get_api(1)
```

## Output

```
Attempt = 1
Trap v Cure
herO v TY
Maru v Solar
Stats v Rogue
Classic v RagnaroK
Dear v Zest
Overwatch - OWL Play-Ins
Philadelphia Fusion v Shanghai Dragons
LNG Academy v SDX Gaming
Gama Dream v Dominus Esports.Y
Team WE Academy v TS Gaming
D7G Esports Club v Invictus Gaming Young
Oh My Dream v Young Miracles
LinGan e-Sports v Bilibili Gaming Junior
Scorpio Game v Suning Gaming-S
Victorious Gaming v FunPlus Phoenix Blaze
87 v Top Esports Challenger
Rogue Warriors Shark v Legend Esport Gaming
Neon Esports v Sunrise
Team Aspirations v Sunrise
Look For Sponsors v Five Brothers
Chiefs Esports Club v MAMMOTH
Overwatch - Contenders
Gen.G esports v Element Mystic
O2 Blast v RunAway
Mindfreak v ORDER
Griffin v SK Telecom T1
J Team v ahq e-Sports club
FunPlus Phoenix v Bilibili Gaming
Top Esports v Royal Never Give Up
Lowkey Esports v Dashing Buffalo
GAM Esports v Team Flash
Lucky Future v Bilibili Gaming
SN Gaming v Team WE
RNGU v Invictus Gaming
Titanar Gaming v LP Esports
G2 Esports v AVANGAR
MiBR v Natus Vincere
FaZe v Renegades
Team Vitality v mousesports
Astralis v CR4ZY
Team Liquid v North
Moops v Brute
eSuba v eXtatus
Royal Youth v SuperMassive
G2 Esports v Fnatic
All Knights v Isurus Gaming
Crest Gaming Act v V3 Esports
Flash v Snow
Fnatic Rising v Excel UK
Vodafone Giants v Origen BCN
KINGZONE DragonX v Afreeca Freecs
MAD Team v G-Rex
Flash Wolves v Hong Kong Attitude
Clutch Gaming v FlyQuest
Flamengo v INTZ
Origen v Splyce
```

Comment: I found it using Fiddler but API didn't seem to like me - I think the redirects false bit is likely important.

Comment: I found it as well. In fact I ignored it several times because of it's weird response.

Comment: Nope. The main attempt that helps get the response is try several times as within  the above script what `if not activated` block does.